# Syntax Error Problam in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I keep getting a syntax error complaint and I can't find out why:

```
cls
set a=.\Data\%Last%.ejl
echo ID: %id% > %a%
echo Last Name: %Last% >> %a%
echo First Name: %First% >> %a%
echo Gender:%Gender% >> %a%
echo Birthday:%Birthday% >> %a%
echo Relation: >> %a%
echo %Relation% >> %a%
```

Comment: Which line of your script is producing the error? Make sure that echo is on, and then see which line is actually causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you - if `%last%` doesn't contain various odd characters.
Some foreign characters are not rendered properly in the default code page.

```
cls
(
   echo ID: %id%
   echo Last Name: %Last%
   echo First Name: %First%
   echo Gender:%Gender%
   echo Birthday:%Birthday%
   echo Relation:
   echo %Relation%
) >".\Data\%Last%.ejl"
```

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess in the absence of information: the variable `last` contains spaces or some "poison" character (those that are significant to `cmd`).

Cure: set the target file to `"%a%"` not `%a%`. The enclosing quotes ensures batch interprets <kbd>Space</kbd> as an ordinary character, not a separator.

To assign a string to a variable, try using `set "string=variable text"` - the enclosing quotes ensure that any trailing spaces on the line are not included in the value assigned.

Note also that any spaces on either side of the `=` in a string-set statement will be included - either in the variablename or the string assigned.

Note also that your design appears to have a problem - what happens where there is more than one "lastname" in your list - `John Doe` and `Jane Doe`?